# Whenever I call onClick function all the other onclick function gets called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am having this problem since a while. Whenever I am trying to click a link and call the onclick function all the other onclick function gets called. I dont know how is this happening

```
<li className={activepage==="dashboard"?'active':''} onClick={changePage("dashboard")} >
    <a href="#">
        <i className="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg" /> Dashboard
    </a>
</li>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" className={activepage==="entries"?'active':''} onClick={changepage("entries")}>
    <a href="#" >
        <i className="fa fa-gift fa-lg" />Entries <i className="fas fa-down-arrow" />
        <span className="arrow" />
    </a>
</li>
```

I am having this problem for a white and i cant find a solution

Comment: looks like `changePage` is not a closure

Comment: What is the code of `changepage("dashboard")`?? Try calling `onClick={() => changePage("dashboard")}`

Comment: also why are you using className? never heared of that in html, normaly its just class="" or id=""..

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp that's because of reactjs code.

Comment: are you working on single page application. I also faced this issue.  When viewmodels are not properly disposed then this type of issue occur.

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp it's JSX code. Not really html but looks like html :) `JSX is a preprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript.`

Comment: For the OP, seems like you have `changepage` and `changePage`. That's one issue. Second, you should use arrow function  `onClick={() => this.changePage("dashboard")}`. And i am guessing you have at the top of the component the function something like `changePage = (value) => { history.push(value) } ` or that you have that function on your props. in that case `this.props.changePage(value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
onClick={changepage("entries")}
```

Try this:

```
onClick={() => changepage("entries")}
```

Comment: how to do that on a functional component?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, then try adding "this" to changepage("entries") like this this.changepage.bind(this,"entries") for example, or if entries is a variable then this.changepage.bind(this,entries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind `changepage.bind(null, "entries")` or you can use

```
() => {
 changepage("entries")
}
```